What kind of a group of numbers will exhibit such property?
Let us take a set of numbers, S. For every group of any numbers taken from S, their average is always an integer. What property or pattern do the numbers of S will definitely follow?

Let $S={11}$. Then it is not divisible by other numbers, except $1$ and $11$, and the average is $11$. What kind of properties are you looking for? Also $S={1,n}$ works for every odd $n$.

First thing in my mind is that all have the same parity: either all even either all odd :-)

@DietrichBurde Sorry, did not consider that we can have just 1 number. Let us say, S has atleast 4 numbers.

@Dominique, it will not necessarily work for, say 4 numbers, and them being 2, 8, 10 and 20 (each being even).

@NavinKumar: I spoke about a first thing, not the only one :-)

You should first determine all such sets $S={a,b,c,d}$ with exactly four distinct numbers. This will give you an insight, and you can improve the question (which might be too general right now).

See also other posts on the same (or similar) question here, or here, or at many other posts.

For any $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in S$ distinct, you need to have $\frac{1}{n}(x_1+\ldots+x_n)\in\mathbb Z$.
For $n=1$, this implies that $S\subseteq \mathbb Z$.
For $n>1$, and say $x\neq y$ in $S$, $x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}\in S$, all distinct, you get $\frac{1}{n}(x_1+\ldots+x_{n-1}+x)\in\mathbb Z$ and$\frac{1}{n}(x_1+\ldots+x_{n-1}+y)\in\mathbb Z$.
Hence by taking the difference, $x-y\in n\mathbb Z$.
We’ve obtained that for any $n<\vert S\vert$, and $x,y\in S$, $x$ and $y$ are congruent modulo $n$. This is not sufficient, as you need the added condition $(\star)$ that the sum of all of them is 0 modulo $\vert S\vert$. That all numbers are congruent modulo $\vert S\vert$ is sufficient, but not necessary.
(For instance $S=\lbrace 1,3,5\rbrace$ has the property you want, and all numbers are indeed congruent modulo 1 and 2, but not modulo 3.)
To construct such a set of size say $n$, you need to find $n$ numbers congruent modulo every $k<n$. Congruence modulo integers less than $n$ reduces by the Chinese remainder theorem to congruence modulo prime powers less than $n$. Hence find, for every prime $p<n$, the maximum power of that prime less than $n$, say $p^{a_p}$. Congruence modulo each of these reduces to congruence modulo the product $\Pi=\prod_{p<n}p^{a_p}$.
Therefore it remains to choose a class modulo $\Pi$, say $c$, and $n$ numbers of the form $k\Pi+c$ which satisfy $(\star)$. The $n-1$ first numbers can be whichever you like, the last can then be chosen to satisfy $(\star)$.
For instance if $n=5$, we have $\Pi=2^2\times 3=12$, and taking $c=1$ we can find the set $S=\lbrace 1,13,25,37,49\rbrace$.
